# MessageCollector in DiscordJS is not working

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to collect messages in a channel as such:

```
const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(channel, m => m.author.id === msg.author.id, { max: 100, maxMatches: 100 });
console.log(collector);
collector.on('collect', (collection, c) => {
    msg.channel.send('Found message.');
    console.log(collection);
    console.log(c);
});
```

However, nothing is logged or sent. Can anybody offer a solution for this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution, I'll post it here in case anybody would find it helpful.

```
const collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(channel, m => m.embeds.length > 0, { max: 10, maxMatches: 10 });
collector.next.then(collec => {
    // console.log(collec);
});
collector.on('collect', (el, c) => {
    msg.channel.send('Found message.');
    console.log(el);
    // console.log(c);
    collector.stop();
});
collector.on('end', (c, r) => {
    // console.log('c');
    msg.channel.send("End Emitted!");
});
```

Comment: Can you accept your own answer, so that the question is marked as solved? You can do that by clicking the tick on the left ;)

Comment: I have to wait 2 days before accepting my own answer (so 1 more day).

Comment: Oh, sorry for that :)